# Checking the ModelState OnPost of only the visible form's properties in razor pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

I created a razor page that has the following properties:

```
[BindProperty]
public CustomerViewModel Customer { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public CustomerContactViewModel Contact { get; set; }
```

Within CustomerViewModel and CustomerContactViewModel I have a bunch of data annotations that make fields required.

This page has 3 views built into one.

Two tabs:
[Customer Info] [Contacts]

[Customer Info] tab has a form to edit a customer and relies on CustomerViewModel

[Contacts] tab has a grid listing initially, but if edit is clicked on a row the user is navigated to the same page but with a query param that makes a form appears in place of the grid.

Here is my problem:

I have two separate submit buttons on the page that use the asp-page-handler property to route to the correct PostAction either SaveCustomer or SaveContact.

When checking if the ModelState is valid at the top of each action, even though the form that is visible on the page is valid, the other form that uses the other model is invalid.

Any ideas on how I can fix this or how I can rework a few things so this isn't an issue?

Here is my view code:

```
@page
@model Messenger.Web.Pages.Customers.EditModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link@(Model.ViewType == EditModel.ViewTypes.EditCustomer ? " active" : "")" id="info-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#info" role="tab" aria-controls="info" aria-selected="true">Info</a>
    </li>
    <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link@(Model.ViewType == EditModel.ViewTypes.EditContact ? " active" : "")" id="contacts-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contacts" role="tab" aria-controls="contacts" aria-selected="false">Contacts</a>
    </li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
    <div class="tab-pane fade @(Model.ViewType == EditModel.ViewTypes.EditCustomer ? " show active" : "")" id="info" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="info-tab">
        <form method="post">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

            <a asp-page="Index" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Cancel</a>
            <button asp-page-handler="SaveCustomer" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success ml-1">Save</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane fade @(Model.ViewType == EditModel.ViewTypes.EditContact ? " show active" : "")" id="contacts" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contacts-tab">
        @if (Model.ViewType == EditModel.ViewTypes.EditCustomer)
        {
            <table class="table">

            </table>
        }
        else
        {
            <form method="post">
                <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

                <a asp-page="./Index" asp-route-CustomerId="@Model.Customer.Id" class="btn btn-outline-secondary">Cancel</a>
                <button asp-page-handler="SaveContact" type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-success ml-1">Save</button>
            </form>
        }
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is the code behind:

```
public enum ViewTypes
{
    EditCustomer = 0,
    EditContact = 1
}

public ViewTypes ViewType { get; set; } = ViewTypes.EditCustomer;

[BindProperty]
public CustomerViewModel Customer { get; set; }

[BindProperty]
public CustomerContactViewModel Contact { get; set; }

public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAsync(int? customerId, string contactId)
{
    if (customerId == null && contactId == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    if (customerId != null)
    {
        var customerFromDb = await _customerRepository.GetByIdWithContactsAsync(customerId.Value);

        if (customerFromDb == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        Customer = _mapper.Map<Customer, CustomerViewModel>(customerFromDb);

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(contactId))
        {
            ViewType = ViewTypes.EditContact;
            var contactFromDb = customerFromDb.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Id == contactId);

            if (contactFromDb == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            Contact = _mapper.Map<HomeUser, CustomerContactViewModel>(contactFromDb);
        }
    }

    return Page();
}

        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSaveCustomerAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        CreateDropdownData();
        return Page();
    }

    var customerFromDb = await _customerRepository.GetByIdAsync(Customer.Id);

    if (customerFromDb == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    customerFromDb.FirstName = Customer.FirstName;
    customerFromDb.MiddleName = Customer.MiddleName;
    customerFromDb.LastName = Customer.LastName;
    customerFromDb.Birthdate = Customer.Birthdate;
    customerFromDb.ActiveIep = Customer.ActiveIep;
    customerFromDb.Active = Customer.Active;
    customerFromDb.EslLep = Customer.EslLep;
    customerFromDb.Grade = Customer.Grade;
    customerFromDb.Homeroom = Customer.Homeroom;
    customerFromDb.Gender = Customer.Gender;

    try
    {
        await _customerRepository.UpdateAsync(customerFromDb);
    }
    catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return RedirectToPage("./", new { CustomerId = Customer.Id });
}

public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostSaveContactAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    var customerContactFromDb = await _homeUserRepository.GetByIdAsync(Contact.Id);

    // Map View Model to Home User (Customer Contact)
    customerContactFromDb.FirstName = Contact.FirstName;
    customerContactFromDb.LastName = Contact.LastName;
    customerContactFromDb.UserName = Contact.Email;
    customerContactFromDb.Email = Contact.Email;
    customerContactFromDb.PhoneNumber = Contact.PhoneNumber;
    customerContactFromDb.EmailNotifications = Contact.EmailNotifications;
    customerContactFromDb.TextNotifications = Contact.TextNotifications;

    await _userManager.UpdateAsync(customerContactFromDb);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contact.Password))
    {
        var resetToken = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(customerContactFromDb);
        await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(customerContactFromDb, resetToken, Contact.Password);
    }

    return RedirectToPage("./", new { CustomerId = customerContactFromDb.CustomerId });
}
```

Comment: Show your views code

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I added it.

Comment: so you are using a common model, that is actually causing the problem, `ModelState` will validate the state of both of your view model properties, better would be to isolate them in different view, don't complicate it with single view

Comment: @EhsanSajjad I previously had them isolated into their own views and it was working, but adding the bootstrap tabber to the top of each view seemed wrong. I guess that was the better way to go since there is only a single model per view. I guess if I am not going to play around with AJAX it isn't worth trying to consolidate and merge things. I am wondering if ViewComponents can help me here.